# I can't understand this proof. If $G$ is a group and $H,K<G$ are groups such that $K<H$ prove that $(G:K)=(G:H)(H:K)$

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation

I know this question it's proved in [prove that $[G:K]$ is finite and $[G:K]=[G:H][H:K]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2156859/prove-that-gk-is-finite-and-gk-ghhk) but I'd like to understand the demonstration which I was given to

This bellow is the demonstration that I have got from my monitor but I didn't get some steps.

$G=\bigcup_{a \in G}aH$ and $H=\bigcup_{b \in K}bK$

**1-Why has he written $G$ and $H$ instead $G:H$ and $H:K$?**

Then he mixed $G$ and $H$ and he got:

$G=\bigcup_{i \in A, j \in A}a_ib_jK$

**2- Why is it $G$ and not $G:K$ ?**

**3-and if it's $G:K$ so why $G:H \cup H:K=G:K$?**

He tried to prove that the last union (the last $G$) has $(G:H)(H:K)$ distinct elements as written bellow:

-If $i \neq i'$ so $a_ib_jK \neq a_{i'} b_j K$ if they both were equal so $a_ib_j \sim a_{i'} b_j$ (**4- where does this equivalence come from?**) that's there exists $k \in K$ such that:

$a_{i'}b_j=a_i b_j K$

**5-Is this correct because the definition of right equivalence?**

The he has written:

$a_{i'}=a_i(b_jKb_j^{-1})$

Then he argued that $b_jKb_j^{-1} \in H$, (**6-why?, 7-why does this help?**)

he argued that $a_{i'}=a_i(b_jKb_j^{-1})$ is equivalent to:

$a_i H=a_{i'}H$ so there's a contradiction. (**8-why contradiction?**)

Why does this equivalence hold? why is it not $a_{i'}=a_iH$?

Then he made another step:

-If $j \neq j'$ so we have $a_i b_j K \neq a_i b_{j'} K$ if they were equal so $a_ib_j \sim a_i b_{j'}$ (**9- why does he use equivalence and not equality here?**) that's there is some $k \in K$ such that $a_ib_{j'}=a_ib_jK$ so:

$b_{j'}=b_jK$

then the same problem again... he argued this is equivalent to:

$b_{j'}K=b_{j}K$

and the proof is complete.

PS:
even if this demonstration is correct, is it poorly clean?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time

Comment: Also, it's "below", not "bellow". I've seen you make that mistake before.

Comment: How would I link each question to the proof?  I'll textbf this I think it'll help

Comment: $G$ is the set; $gH$ are the cosets. The set is equal to the union of the cosets. $G:H$ is a **number**. The equation "$G:H\cup H:K = G:K$" does not even parse.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is an element of $G$, and $H$ a subgroup of $G$, then $xH$ is a *subset* of $G$.  By definition, $xH = \{ xh : h \in H\}$.  Sets of the forms $xH$ are called **left cosets** of $H$ in $G$.

$[G : H]$ is the **index** of $H$ in $G$.  It is by definition the number of *distinct* subsets of $G$ of the form $xH$.

On the other hand, $G/H$ is the set of left cosets of $H$ in $G$.  So, $G/H$ is not a subset of $G$, but rather its elements are themselves subsets of $G$.  Thus $[G : H]$ is the cardinality of the set $G/H$.

**1, 2, 3**: The notation

$$G = \bigcup\limits_{a \in G} aH$$

is correct.
This is to say, $G$ is the union of its left cosets.

The statement

$$H = \bigcup\limits_{b \in H} bK$$

is similarly correct.  The statement

$$G = \bigcup\limits_{i,j} a_i b_j K$$

is also correct and not a mix up.  This is because

$$a_i  \Bigg( \bigcup\limits_j b_j K \Bigg) = \bigcup\limits_j a_i b_j K$$

and therefore

$$G = \bigcup\limits_i a_i H = \bigcup\limits_i a_i \Bigg( \bigcup\limits_j b_j K \Bigg) = \bigcup\limits_i \bigcup\limits_j a_i b_j K = \bigcup\limits_{i,j} a_i b_j K.$$

Comment: Why is $G$ the union of left cosets? $|G|=|G:H|=|G:K|$?

Comment: Why is $G$ equal to the union of left cosets?  I hope it is at least clear to you that the union of the left cosets is a subset of $G$, right?

Comment: you are right, sorry, I get confused about union as if it was $\{a_1H,...,a_nH\}$

Comment: Yes so you see easily that $G$ is equal to the union of its left cosets.  Now it is not true that $|G| = [G : H]$ (the number of elements in $G$ is not equal to the number of left cosets of $H$ in $G$), but rather $|G| = [G : H] \times |H|$.